# How to handle request errors in react/redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk

I've been searching for some solutions about handling requests errors like an invalid password error when trying to login into the server via a redux action.

The most robust solution I found was having a reducer that takes care of the errors while the component bases what it is showing on the state given by the reducer.

Example:

I have a reducer property "emailNotValidated" that gets true if the server responds that the user email was not validated yet, then my component will be shown slightly different with options to resend the verification e-mail and more.

The problem is that: What if the user gets out of the login page and then returns to it? I don't want him/her to find the verification option since I want the login page to be "renewed". Do I have to dispatch and action to "reset" this reducer every time I open this component/page?

Comment: Are you using the data outside the given component? If not why not just use state?

Comment: No. Should I just call a callback inside the action to warn the login component about the error instead of dispatching an error action?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a React project that has several modules mainly for:

- User
- Blog
- Comments

In your action you can do something like this:

```
// actions/user.js
export const userMessageError = (payload, message) => {
    type: 'USER_ERR_MESSAGE',
    error: {
       message,
       payload
    },
}
```

You can actually place some error handling case inside of each of the module's reducer like so:

```
// reducer/user.js

case 'USER_ERR_MESSAGE':
// You might want to set the request payload and the error message
// to the state in order for you to actually know what's going on
//
// Then you could have a toast or a modal in the container or inside
// your component to actually display the actual error message
```

Doing this, you can actually know which module returns an error, what the payload is and actually getting the error message.

You might not need the payload to be returned, but it is all up to you and your preference.